# Marshaling object with StringBuffer attributes

Tags: java, jaxb

When marshaling an object via JAXB with a StringBuffer attribute, that attribute becomes blank. I wrote a small program to demonstrate the problem:

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class JaxbTest {

    private String valueOne;
    private StringBuffer valueTwo;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        JaxbTest object = new JaxbTest();
        object.setValueOne("12345");
        object.setValueTwo(new StringBuffer("54321"));

        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(JaxbTest.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.marshal(object, System.out);
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getValueOne() {
        return valueOne;
    }

    public void setValueOne(String valueOne) {
        this.valueOne = valueOne;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public StringBuffer getValueTwo() {
        return valueTwo;
    }

    public void setValueTwo(StringBuffer valueTwo) {
        this.valueTwo = valueTwo;
    }
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><jaxbTest><valueOne>12345</valueOne><valueTwo/></jaxbTest>
```

Does anyone know why "valueTwo" is not being marshaled correctly? BTW, i am using java 1.6.0_22.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: StringBuffer is not the same as String (obv!), so it is handled differently. Either make sure jaxb won't notice that (see Answer by Guillaume below) or, which is my recommendations, don't use a StringBuffer as a value for a jaxb attribute. You can use the buffer to create the String you want, then call `object.setValueTwo(buffer.toString());` to use the created String for the jaxb object.

Comment: Good question. There should be exception if marshaller can't deal with passing object. I think you should try to specify your own binder (http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/Binder.html)

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using JAXB's XmlAdapter for this use case:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that JaxB does not know how to serialize a StringBuffer. What I would do to solve this kind of issues, is to have a pair of getters/setters:

1. the one you currently have
2. one which returns a String and annotated with @XmlElement

   import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
   import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
   import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
   import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class JaxbTest {

```
private String valueOne;
private StringBuffer valueTwo;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    JaxbTest object = new JaxbTest();
    object.setValueOne("12345");
    object.setValueTwo(new StringBuffer("54321"));

    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(JaxbTest.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.marshal(object, System.out);
}

@XmlElement
public String getValueOne() {
    return valueOne;
}

public void setValueOne(String valueOne) {
    this.valueOne = valueOne;
}

public StringBuffer getValueTwo() {
    return valueTwo;
}

public void setValueTwo(StringBuffer valueTwo) {
    this.valueTwo = valueTwo;
}

@XmlElement
public String getValueTwoString() {
    return valueTwo!=null?valueTwo.toString():null;
}

public void setValueTwoString(String valueTwo) {
    this.valueTwo = new StringBuffer(valueTwo);
}
```

}

I am not completely sure, but I think that if you use @XmlElement(name="valueTwo") on the getValueTwoString() method, you should get exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

When I have marshaling issues with simple types, I tend to create an extra getter (and possibly setter) to simplify it. Then I add an @XmlIgnore to the main field and set the name of the new field to that of the old one. Example below:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class JaxbTest {

    private String valueOne;
    private StringBuffer valueTwo;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        JaxbTest object = new JaxbTest();
        object.setValueOne("12345");
        object.setValueTwo(new StringBuffer("54321"));

        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(JaxbTest.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.marshal(object, System.out);
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getValueOne() {
        return valueOne;
    }

    public void setValueOne(String valueOne) {
        this.valueOne = valueOne;
    }

    @XmlIgnore
    public StringBuffer getValueTwo() {
        return valueTwo;
    }

    public void setValueTwo(StringBuffer valueTwo) {
        this.valueTwo = valueTwo;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="valueTwo")
    public String getValueTwoString() {
        return valueTwo.toString();
    }

    public void setValueTwoString(String valueTwo) {
        this.valueTwo = new StringBuffer(valueTwo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the prompt and wonderful answers!!

I got this problem when using the servicemix-exec component in ServiceMix 4.2, which is caused by this [ExecResponse](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/servicemix/components/tags/servicemix-exec-2010.01/src/main/java/org/apache/servicemix/exec/marshaler/ExecResponse.java?view=markup) class. It is using a StringBuffer for the "outputData" and "errorData" attribute.